# Interface method cannot implement another interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, error-handling, interface

I can't find why it doesn't work. I want to do a simple interface that contains a generic method which implements IError interface

```
   public class ErrorHandler<T> : IErrorHandler<ErrorInfo>
  {
    public Task HandleAsync() where T : IError
    {
        //code
    }
  }


  public interface IErrorHandler<T>
  {
    Task HandleAsync() where T : IError;
  }

  public interface IError
  {
    //code
  }

  public class ErrorInfo : IError
  {
    //code
  }
```

Compile error shows 'Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations'

Comment: (As a side-note, it's very odd to declare a type parameter but never actually use it...)

Comment: isn't that obvious: your method simply is not generic, so you cannot provide a where-constraint. Your class however may get the constraint, as it *is* generic

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error message says it all - you've added a constraint for the `T` type parameter, but you've added it in a place which doesn't declare that type parameter. It should be on the interface declaration, not the method declaration. Note that you say "that contains a generic method" - it doesn't. That isn't a generic method, it's a non-generic method in a generic class/interface.

Your class and interface should look like this:

```cs
public class ErrorHandler<T> : IErrorHandler<ErrorInfo> where T : IError
{
    public Task HandleAsync() 
    {
        // Code
    }
}

public interface IErrorHandler<T> where T : IError
{
    Task HandleAsync();
}
```

If you *actually* wanted a generic method, it would look like this:

```cs
public class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    public Task HandleAsync<T>() where T : IError
    {
        // Code
    }
}

public interface IErrorHandler
{
    Task HandleAsync<T>() where T : IError;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. second option doesn't compiles 'Using the generic type IErrorHandler<T> requires 1 type arguments'

Comment: @JUrma: Whoops, had actually forgotten to update the interface to be non-generic. Should work now. But I *suspect* you want the generic type really.